# Unit testing [DataSource(dataProvider,connectionString, dataAccessMethod)] not working for single value in xml

Tags: unit-testing, data-driven-tests

I am trying to run same test case multiple times using datasource.And for that I am using [DataSource(dataProvider,connectionString, dataAccessMethod)] attribute under [Testmethod].
It is working with two or more values in xml but not working for single value can u please help me?

Comment: Can you please post some sample code as what you are referring as "value" is not clear?

Comment: Now it is working xml file which i was referring was not in the required format.
Format required is:  
<Browsers>
<Browser>IE</Browser>
<Browser>Chrome</Browser>
<Browser>Firefox</Browser>
</Browsers>